# CodeIgniter redirect me to the home page sometime

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using `CodeIgniter v2.0.2` and I hosted my project online but during working on different part or submitting form, it automatically redirects me to the main page or index page.

I read the below reference but doesn't help.
https://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-66250.html

Here is my `.htacess` file content

```
# BEGIN Allow Sucuri
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^sucuri-(.*)\.php$ - [L]
</IfModule>
# END Allow Sucuri
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|aksa|js|css|jpg|gif|jpeg|JPEG|pdf|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project_dir/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please show the controller code which is handling the GET/POST request?

Comment: Please post your code in which you are facing problem

Comment: i don't understand how someone with upwards of 1k rep doesn't know by now to post their code as it is germane to almost every question on here.

Comment: @Alex, This is a general issue with CodeIgniter and no problem with specific part of the code. If you open the link I have include in my post, you will see what is the problem.

Comment: It happens randomly anywhere not in one controller or function.

Comment: if it were a general issue with codeigniter then it would have been officially noted somewhere. not to mention a problem as big as that is typically quickly resolved.

Comment: Maybe someone else faced such a problem and found an alternative for that if they want to share with me the alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check submitform action function and debug might be possible to redirect some where. try with exit step wise.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar issue about this. I fixed this by adding `type="button"` in the `<button>` HTML tag. If this does not work, please post your code.

Comment: The problem is not with buttons and it happens anywhere randomly.

Comment: Have you tried turning on and checking the logs if there's an error?

Comment: Yes I checked but no error to identify that problem.

Comment: Are you using MY_Controller to extend your controllers?

Comment: No, using CI_Controller

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess.

Comment: Is this issue happens when you submit a form only?

Comment: Mostly yes but when I navigating to another page it happens as well.